# Flatten an entry to list mapping to a two column correspondence in Excel

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

I am facing a problem in Excel that I have quiten often and that I really want to automize or semiautomize.

I have entries A_x being followed by a non-empty list of B_y's. Now I want to flatten the entry to list mapping to a simple two column list for easier processing as shown in the example below.

In fact my example is quite larger than shown here and I want to avoid a dull copy and paste hack.

Can this be achieved without using VBA with simple Excel functions?

[image: Example of flattening list]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(B2:D5<>"",A2:A5),3),TOCOL(B2:D5,1))
```

Comment: I am really not an Excel expert. There seems to be problem when entering the formula. Only first columns is shown, but the second one is missing. Any idea how to remedy this. First column seems to be correct.

Comment: @Aleph0, can you try again with given formula?

Comment: So cool and so easy to comprehend. Many thanks. Works also for large datasets.

Answer (score 3):

### Transform Data: Unpivot, Skip Blanks

```
=LET(data,A2:D5,
    d,IF(data="","",data),
    v,DROP(d,,1),
    vc,TOCOL(v),
    rc,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(v)),TAKE(d,,1))),
    FILTER(HSTACK(rc,vc),vc<>""))
```

[image]

**LAMBDA**

--> Name Manager e.g. `USB`

```
=LAMBDA(data,LET(d,IF(data="","",data),v,DROP(d,,1),vc,TOCOL(v),FILTER(HSTACK(TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(v)),TAKE(d,,1))),vc),vc<>"")))
```

--> Anywhere in the Workbook, e.g.:

```
=USB(A2:D5)
```

**Edit**

JvdV's great idea lead me to this:

```
=LET(data,A2:D5,
    ToColNB,LAMBDA(nbdata,data,TOCOL(IFS(nbdata<>"",data),2)),
    d,IF(data="","",data),
    v,DROP(d,,1),
    HSTACK(ToColNB(v,TAKE(d,,1)),ToColNB(v,v)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try-

```
=LET(x,DROP(REDUCE("",TOCOL(A2:A4&"|"&B2:D4),LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(x,"|")))),1),FILTER(x,CHOOSECOLS(x,2)<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: Works as being promised. I really need some time to digest this onliner.

Comment: After trying it with a 2000 lines table sometimes containing up to 10 columns the function just crashes excel. So it seems, that this approach does not scale with large number of lines.