How do I paste transpose from multiple rows to two columns - with repeat headers in one column and value in second - using Excel VBA macro?
My data looks like following:



Header A
Data 1
Data 2
Data 3
Data n




Header B
Data 1
Data 2
Data 3
Data n


Header C
Data 1
Data 2
Data 3
Data n



And the expected output is :



Header A
Data 1




Header A
Data 2


Header A
Data 3


Header B
Data 1


Header B
Data 2


Header B
Data 3


Header C
Data 1


Header C
Data 2


Header C
Data 3



I am currently using following, but it gives me a pure transpose, instead of required output:
Sub CopyPaste_ValuesTranspose()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1") '<< source sheet name

Set ws2 = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)) '<< new Sheet

ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy

ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues, Transpose:=True

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ws2.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Any suggestions?

No need to do this by VBA - you can use a formula: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77981513/flatten-an-entry-to-list-mapping-to-a-two-column-correspondence-in-excel/77981760#77981760

You can also use power query as well to accomplish this, especially handy if your data is in a table format. unpivot columns and you can simply right-click refresh the output table as new data is introduced.


Using PQ to transform table without coding

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"


